# Pass two different array values to controller to detach them with Laravel

Tags: laravel, controller, parameter-passing

I want to detach some data from my database. I have a table on my view that shows some data with checkboxes. Every tag has it own checkbox. I want to pass all the tag_id's from the tags I've checked. To detach them I also need the domain_id. I've tried some things out but couldn't figure out how I can pass all the domain_id with the tag_id's I've marked.

```
<tbody>
    {!! Form::open(['action' => 'DomainController@detach', 'method' => 'post']) !!}    
               @foreach($domains as $domain)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $domain->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $domain->tld }}</td>
                        <td id="hello">
                            @foreach($domain->tags as $tag)
                                {{ $tag->name }},<br>
                            @endforeach
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="domain_id[]" type="hidden" value="{{ $domain->id }}">
                            @foreach($domain->tags as $tag)
                                <input type="checkbox" name="tag_id[]" value="{{$tag->id}}"><br>
                            @endforeach
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
</tbody>


<div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >Action<span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a>
                    <button>Send</button>
            </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Now I want to get every tag_id and the domain_id of the tags if I mark them with a tick.

As a output I need something like this:

```
[0] = "domain_id" : 5,
      "tag_id" : [0] => 1,
                 [1] => 2,
                 [2] => 3,
[1] = "domain_id" : 6,
      "tag_id" : [0] => 10,
                 [1] => 11,
                 [2] => 12,
```

currently.. this is what I get

```
 {"domain_id":["5","6","10","13","15","18","19","22","23","24","28"],"tag_id":["273","286","285"]}
```

I've just marked tags from the domain with id 5, but it gave me all domain_id's and I couln't figure out why..

Comment: Why don't you prefix the tag_id value with the domain_id in the value parameter separated by a delimeter (i.e.: 6:10). Use some kind of indicator that you can than explode in your controller while processing the request.

Comment: can you give me an example? cause I didn't really now what do you mean

Comment: ( I should better say I know what you mean but don't really know how I can make this

Answer (score 0):

A form won't output values in the way you want as it cannot generate subarrays, so as mentioned in my comment, you will have to improvise. Your bottom line is you need to associate the domain_id with each tag_id in some way so you can database it, or whatever.

I suggest creating your tag checkbox like this in your view

```
<td>
    @foreach($domain->tags as $tag)
         <input type="checkbox" name="tag_id[]" value="{{$domain->id}}:{{$tag->id}}"><br>
    @endforeach
</td>
```

when submitted, it should format the tag_id in the request object like this

```
[0] = "tag_id" : [0] => 5:1,
                 [1] => 5:2,
                 [2] => 5:3,
                 [3] => 6:10,
                 [4] => 6:11,
                 [5] => 6:12,
```

Now you can loop over the tag_id array and separate the domain_id and tag_id fields to do whatever you need to (your example didn't say what you wanted to to do with them)

```
foreach ($request->tag_id as $item) {
    $arrItem = explode(':', $item);
    // $arrItem[0] is your domain_id for the tag_id $arrItem[1]
    // other logic here 
}
```